# Weird layout using GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

I have several methods which create their own component, `JButton` or `JLabel` in a `JPanel`. Then I have a separate method which adds all these `JPanels` the the `JFrame`. I also use `gridx` and `gridy` on the JPanels to position them how I want. This is: lookreply on the left, then top right the title and below in a `2X2` table quit, restart, pickup and hello. However my current code when run displays a weird, random layout.

The lookreply is on the left, but then to the right is quit, a space, restart then hello all vertical. pickup and title aren't seen. I dont know why this is happening.

Please see my code below.:

```
public class GUI extends JPanel
{
/**
 * Creation of variables used throughout the GUI Class. 
 */
//JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GUI g = new GUI();

    g.create();
}

private void create()
{
    JFrame screen = new JFrame("Dungeon of Doom");
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    //set size to full screen. 
    screen.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);   

    //Add all JPanes to screen
    screen.add(lookReply(), c);
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;

    screen.add(title(), c);
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;

    screen.add(quit(), c);
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;

    screen.add(restart(), c);
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridx = 2;

    screen.add(pickup(), c);
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;

    screen.add(hello(), c);
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 2;

    screen.setVisible(true);
}
```

One of the methods (quit)

```
private JPanel quit()
{
    JPanel quitPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton quit = new JButton("QUIT");
    quitPanel.add(quit, c);


    return quitPanel;
}
```

All the other methods are pretty much the same except the title is a a `JLabel` and the table iterates to create a `5x5` table of `JLabel` within its own `JPanel`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why does your class extend JPanel? You have a method "create()" that creates the JFrame and adds components to the frame. You don't add the GUI class to the frame, so why is it a JPanel? Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr I thought when doing anything with GUI you had to extend JPanel? I must be wrong. And how do I go about posting my SSCCE? is it just in the qu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was doing this.
As seen in the code I was adding the component before setting the layout.

```
screen.add(lookReply(), c);
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridx = 0;
```

whereas it should be

```
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridx = 0;
screen.add(lookReply(), c);
```